# How to convert Func<T,bool> to Expression<Func<T,bool>>

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda, expression-trees

I have a Func like this :

```
 Func<MyClass, bool> func = x=>Id == 5;
```

How I can convert it to :

```
 Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>
```

Comment: Expression is an Intermediate Representation of a Lambda function. Func is the compiled lambda function itself. Don't think you can convert between the two. Why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Func<MyClass, bool> func = x=>Id == 5;
Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> expr = mc => func(mc);
```

Comment: This actually sets `expr` to be a call to a delegate which takes a `MyClass` and returns a `bool`. `expr` wont hold a syntax tree for the actual lambda.

Comment: Yes, it is. So what? Perhaps the author of the question should be just that.

Comment: This should not be accepted answer. The method does not get converted to expression whatsoever.

Comment: The method converts to Expression.

Answer (score 14):

You can just write:

```
Expression<Func<MyClass,bool>> expr = x=>Id == 5;
```

This will set `expr` to be an expression tree for `Id == 5`.

If you do:

```
Func<MyClass, bool> func = x=>Id == 5;
Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> expr = mc => func(mc);
```

Then this will set `expr` to be an expression tree for a call to `func`, not an expression tree for the body of `func`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an expression that represents the call to the delegate you created. But most of the time, when you're using `Expression`s, you do that to understand what the code does (e.g. to convert it to SQL). And you can't do that with an expression to invoke an opaque function.